# one side of brake pad retention problem (i.e. attached to rim)

Tags: brakes, shimano, rim-brake

my front wheel brake pad (only one side) is still attached to the rim after I released brake lever. How do I fix this problem?

I believe it is a cantilever brake.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Its a good start but we need more info, like what kind of brakes are they - caliper, cantilevers or V-brakes?  Feel free to use http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/37327/edit to edit and expand your question.

Comment: I believe it is a cantilever brake.

Comment: A cantilever adjustment should be like @mocniak 's answer.  Its not a caliper brake which is completely different.   Give it a try, and if it works for you then accept that answer as correct with the little tick/check box on the left side.

Comment: It needs to be adjusted.  And possibly the cables will need lubrication and/or replacement.

Answer (score 2):

If it's v-brake you should have screws regulating spring tension on each brake arm, try to screw in a little bit one on the side where pads stays attached to the rim.

[image: Shledon Brown's picture]

Comment: You can also take that portion apart and rebend the spring for more tension as well if it is old and has lost some of its springy-ness

Comment: On my bike, I tightened the screw all the way on the sticky side and loosened the screw on the other side but the sticky side still doesn't move. What further steps can I do?